# How can I avoid different windows of the same app get folded in at the dock?

Tags: macos, dock, application-switcher

Some times I have apps opened with more than one windows, like Chrome. How can I see in the Dock one icon per each windows (even they are of the same app) that I have open?

Would be nice know how to switch using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or something like that between all the windows opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your System prefs are set,  <kbd>F3</kbd>  will do a variety of window-juggling tasks…

If Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard is set to default, with "Use all F1, F2…" *unchecked* then they will work as stated, if it's *checked* you will need to add the  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  key to each of these commands.

<kbd>F3</kbd>  will toggle Mission Control - all windows of all apps & Desktops spread out so you can see them.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F3</kbd>  will toggle desktop view only.

<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F3</kbd>  will show all windows of only the frontmost app *[this is likely to be the closest to what you need.]

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>F3</kbd>  will do the same as just  <kbd>F3</kbd>  … only really really *slowly* [for presentations etc]

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>F3</kbd>  will bring up Mission Control prefs, where you can tweak other behaviour.

You can also go directly to a given tab by right-clicking the app icon in the Dock, though it only shows the frontmost tab's title for each window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is really frustrating don't have this feature on Mac.

Comment: Ahh… a late thought, I'll add to the answer - you can go to a specific window if you right click the icon in the Dock - but the label only shows the frontmost tab's title

Comment: Yes, already realize that. Thanks again, I'm really impressed that OS X don't have this feature, very uncomfortable ;)

Comment: Horses for courses, I guess - personally even on Windows I consolidate to stop it doing the, imo, irritating one-window-per-icon thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

The dock does not shows the windows but the applications.

But once you choose an application you can switch among windows with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

To see all the open windows you can use exposé: press <kbd>F10</kbd> to show all the windows of the current application or <kbd>F9</kbd> for all the windows. You can also configure a gesture in the system preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So no way in Mac of have an easy to access list of all the windows I have opened? or a shortcut to switch between all the windows no matter if they are of the same app or not?

Comment: See my edit. Not the same but could maybe work ...

Comment: None of those keys worked.